# InfoPath Rich Text not displaying in Read mode

Tags: infopath

I have a problem that I can't seem to get a solution to.

I have a SharePoint 2010 list, which I then edit the form in InfoPath 2010.  I then added a Rich Text field, follow by a Multiple-Selection field, and then a few more Rich Text fields.

Once deployed, I then created a new list item and filled out the whole form and saved it.

When I open the new item to read it, I noticed that all the Rich text fields after the Multiple-Selection field does NOT get displayed at all!  It's as if those fields were never filled out!

But when I go to edit the item, I do see all the content in those Rich Text fields!

This is only happening in FireFox, Chrome, and Safari.... in Internet Explorer, I don't have this issue at all.

Has anyone else noticed something like this before?  Is this a bug?

Comment: Did you get a solution for your issue ?  I am also having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Publishing of an Infopath form onto a Sharepoint list should enable invoking through a ribbon or by clicking on presented by Sharepoint links in browser:

- **displayifs.aspx**
- **editifs.aspx**
- **newifs.aspx**

instead of default Sharepoint form web pages

- **DispForm.aspx**
- **EditForm.aspx**
- **NewForm.aspx**

i.e. the use of first three instead of last three.

Though it is still possible to manually tweak configuration to use its mixture for invoking them context-sensitively (by generated Sharepoint link and from ribbon). One can also simply access any of (navigate to) them through direct links.

So, it can be a bless to by-pass the default behaviour or pain for those who are caught by Sharepoint automatic configurations overriding your manual one (or vice versa)